# How to fix? it show that the disposable object is never disposed

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
  conn.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
  conn.Open()
  Dim dt As New DataTable
  Dim ds As New DataSet
  ds.Tables.Add(dt)
  Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
  da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Staff where Staff ID = '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%';", conn)
  da.Fill(dt)
  DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
  conn.Close()
End Sub
```

> da.fill(dt)  -- systax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Staff ID = '%1%".'

Comment: Please don't make your subject the entire question. I don't know what you're asking.  What you **are** asking for is an attack through [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) by not sanitising your `txtSearch.Text` input

Comment: using `=` with a % (i.e. wildcard) in SQL makes no sense. If you want wildcards to take effect then use `LIKE`. This is also vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://bobby-tables.com/) attacks - you need to use [parameterised queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types#working-with-parameter-placeholders). And it's hard to see what this alleged syntax error has to do with disposing of objects.

Comment: "Staff ID" needs to be in brackets since it is a field that contains a space.  You don't need the DataSet.  DataAdapters can open and close a connection for you, so you don't need to explicitly do that.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent against SQL Injections, you should use SQL parameters instead.

Update your function to the following function instead:

```
Public Function selectSQLFunction()
  Dim conn as  New SqlClient.SqlConnection
  conn.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
  conn.Open()

  Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
  Dim selectSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM Staff WHERE Staff ID = ?"  
  Dim selectCMD AS OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(selectSQL, conn)  

  da.SelectCommand = selectCMD  
' Add parameters and set values.  '
selectCMD.Parameters.Add( _  
  "@ID", OleDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = txtSearch.Text  

  Dim staffDS As DataSet = New DataSet  
  da.Fill(staffDS, "Staff")  

  dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.dataTable("Staff").DefaultView
  conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: This code is subject to Sql injection. Please change your answer to reflect the use of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your question title suggests you are asking about an 'Object never disposed' error.  If so, try rewriting your code like this:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim ds As New DataSet
ds.Tables.Add(dt)
using da As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Staff where Staff ID LIKE '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%';", new oleDbConnection(dbProvider & dbSource))
   'NOTE: Change above Select query to use parameters as per other answer'
   da.Fill(dt) 'No need to open or close connection with data adapter'
end using 'This disposes the data adapter 
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
```